# Resizing element using angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I wanted to make two stretchable rectangles which can be resized horizontally(both left and right).But the problem with my current code is that once i resize my first rectangle(in red),the second rectangle(in blue) automatically jumps to the initial position of the first rectangle.Please help me to fix this.
I am attaching my code along with the output images.

html file:

```
<div class="rectangle" [ngStyle]="style" mwlResizable [validateResize]="validate" 
[enableGhostResize]="true" 
[resizeSnapGrid]="{ left: 1, right: 1 }"  (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)">
<div class="resize-handle-left" mwlResizeHandle [resizeEdges]="{ left: true }"></div>
<div class="resize-handle-right" mwlResizeHandle [resizeEdges]="{ right: true }"></div>
</div>

<div class="rectangle1" [ngStyle]="style1" mwlResizable [validateResize]="validate1" 
[enableGhostResize]="true" 
[resizeSnapGrid]="{ left: 1, right: 1 }" (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd1($event)">
<div class="resize-handle-left1" mwlResizeHandle [resizeEdges]="{ left: true }"></div>
<div class="resize-handle-right1" mwlResizeHandle [resizeEdges]="{ right: true }"></div>
</div>
```

css file:

```
.rectangle {
 position: relative;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: red;
 }
.rectangle1 {
 position: relative;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: blue;
 }
.resize-handle-left,
.resize-handle-right {
 position: absolute;
 height: 50px;
 cursor: col-resize;
 width: 5px;
 }
 .resize-handle-left {
 left: 0;
 }
.resize-handle-right {
 right: 0;
 }
.resize-handle-left1,
.resize-handle-right1 {
 position: absolute;
 height: 50px;
 cursor: col-resize;
 width: 5px;
 }
 .resize-handle-left1 {
 left: 0;
 }
.resize-handle-right1 {
 right: 0;
 }
```

.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ResizeEvent } from 'angular-resizable-element';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
constructor() { }

public style: object = {};
public style1: object = {};

validate(event: ResizeEvent): boolean {
const MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX: number = 50;
if (
  event.rectangle.width &&
  event.rectangle.height &&
  (event.rectangle.width < MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX ||
    event.rectangle.height < MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX)
   ) {
  return false;
 }
return true;
}

validate1(event: ResizeEvent): boolean {
const MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX: number = 50;
if (
  event.rectangle.width &&
  event.rectangle.height &&
  (event.rectangle.width < MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX ||
    event.rectangle.height < MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX)
  ) {
  return false;
  }
return true;
}

onResizeEnd(event: ResizeEvent): void {
this.style = {
  position: 'fixed',
  left: `${event.rectangle.left}px`,
  top: `${event.rectangle.top}px`,
  width: `${event.rectangle.width}px`,
  height: `${event.rectangle.height}px`
  };
 }

 onResizeEnd1(event: ResizeEvent): void {
 this.style1 = {
  position: 'fixed',
  left: `${event.rectangle.left}px`,
  top: `${event.rectangle.top}px`,
  width: `${event.rectangle.width}px`,
  height: `${event.rectangle.height}px`
  };
 }
}
```

Links to the output:

[On refreshing my page](https://ibb.co/803trRm)

[problem with resizing](https://ibb.co/XJKzD12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove css property `top` and `position`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ResizeEvent } from 'angular-resizable-element';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

public style: object = {};
public style1: object = {};

validate(event: ResizeEvent): boolean {
const MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX: number = 50;
if (
  event.rectangle.width &&
  event.rectangle.height &&
  (event.rectangle.width < MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX ||
    event.rectangle.height < MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX)
   ) {
  return false;
 }
return true;
}

validate1(event: ResizeEvent): boolean {
const MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX: number = 50;
if (
  event.rectangle.width &&
  event.rectangle.height &&
  (event.rectangle.width < MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX ||
    event.rectangle.height < MIN_DIMENSIONS_PX)
  ) {
  return false;
  }
return true;
}

onResizeEnd(event: ResizeEvent): void {
this.style = {

  left: `${event.rectangle.left-8}px`,
  width: `${event.rectangle.width}px`,
  height: `${event.rectangle.height}px`
  };
 }

 onResizeEnd1(event: ResizeEvent): void {
 this.style1 = {
  left: `${event.rectangle.left-8}px`,
  width: `${event.rectangle.width}px`,
  height: `${event.rectangle.height}px`
  };
 }
}
```

Comment: It just solves our current purpose.While scrolling the page leftward or rightward,the position of the rectangle remains fix.How to solve this issue now?

Comment: i have updated code, now it should work While scrolling the page

Answer (score 0):

**resizeEnd** is the same event for both the rectangles. So when it fires function attached to this event will be called. In your code
    functions:- **onResizeEnd and onResizeEnd1** must be called togather
    when **resizeEnd** event occurs and the values of another rectangle
    got reset.

---

try to create separate events for both the rectangles.

let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: Since I do not have the whole code available with me, Its hard to do so. Can you please create demo on stackblitz